How can I persist the chaindata of my ethereum private network?
I have build a ehtereum private network with docker and it could run normaly. But if I try to persist the chaindata by using volumes, the node will connect mainnet, instead of my private network.
Here is my docker-compose and Docker file code with normal start:
docker-compose file:
version: '3.7'

services:
  node:
    hostname: geth-node
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./data/keystore:/root/.ethereum/keystore
    command:
      --identity "node0" 
      --datadir /root/.ethereum 
      --keystore /root/.ethereum/keystore 
      --mine 
      --miner.threads=1 
      --miner.etherbase=${ACCOUNT_ADDRESS} 
      --networkid=${NETWORK_ID} 
      --http 
      --http.addr='0.0.0.0' 
      --http.corsdomain "*" 
      --http.api='eth,net,web3,personal,miner,admin' 
      --bootnodes='' 
      --port 30303 
      --nat extip:${IP} 
      --allow-insecure-unlock 
      --nodiscover 
      --authrpc.addr localhost 
      --authrpc.port 8551
    ports:
      - "30303:30303"  
      - "30303:30303/udp"  
      - "8545:8545"  
      - "8551:8551"
    networks:
      priv-eth-net:


networks:
  priv-eth-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.31.1.0/24

Dockerfile.
FROM ethereum/client-go:release-1.11

ARG ACCOUNT_PASSWORD

COPY genesis.json /tmp
RUN cat /tmp/genesis.json

RUN geth init /tmp/genesis.json  \
  && rm -f ~/.ethereum/geth/nodekey 

ENTRYPOINT ["geth"]

This is genesis.file
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 123,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "ethash": {}
  },
  "difficulty": "400000",
  "gasLimit": "12000000",
  "alloc": {
      "77696b3b83037ce9a0f90d38b0af8e717d74591f": { "balance": "1000000000000000000" }}
}

and it connects to my private network rightful

But if I replace '- ./data/keystore:/root/.ethereum/keystore' to '- ./data:/root/.ethereum'. It will connect the mainnet
so how can I run my private network and persist the chaindata?

Did you create a genesis file or called geth init? If it isn't provided the node connects to mainnet.

Yes, I have created. This is why I could connect to my private network If I just specify the keystore path as the first terminal screenshot. But if I I replace '- ./data/keystore:/root/.ethereum/keystore' to '- ./data:/root/.ethereum', it will connect mainnet
